# mysql shema for eshop with services of multiple types

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im creating an eshop with Laravel and im designing the database. The eshop will have a variety of service types, each service must belong to a category and each service must have name ,price and description. When a user adds a service to the cart, he must fill in some necessary fields (which are totally different for each service, even for the services on the same category) for this particular service in order to go to the check-out.
I'm struggling all day to find the most efficient way on doing this.
One option is to create multiple tables for each product type for example:

```
Service  (category)
1.id        PK
2.name

Service_item  
1.id  PK
2.service_id  FK
3.title
4.description
5.price

Service1_attributes
1.id PK
2.service_order_id    FK
3.service_item_id     FK
4.color
5.size
6...

Service2_attributes
1.id PK
2.service_order_id
3.service_item_id     FK
4.width
5.height
6..

and then create the order table:

Order
1.id    PK
2.user_id
3.totalPrice
```

I believe that this is not the best way on order to achieve what im looking for, any help would be appreciated because im totally stuck with this one. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood from your description:

**Categories**

1. ID (PK)
2. Name
3. ...

**Services**

1. ID (PK)
2. Name
3. Description
4. Price
5. Category_ID

**Service_attributes**

1. ID (PK)
2. Service_ID
3. Name

**Users**

1. ID (PK)
2. Name
3. ...

You provided very little data about the whole problem, try to give us some usable example on how the system is supposed to work so we can help you with the scheme.